# Refactoring a Controller containing Many-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, refactoring, many-to-many

I'm following a tutorial on making a blog and I was wondering how I can refactor some of the codes that look a mess. Specifically the many-to-many relationship while parsing in tags. Is there a better way to reduce this into a smaller function on the controller?

```
  public ActionResult Create(int? id, string title, string body, DateTime datetime, string tags)
   {
      Post post = GetPost(id);
      post.Title = title;
      post.Body = body;
      post.Tags.Clear();
// I'D Like to refactor this point on to look something like this: ParseTags(tags); 
rather than this
      tags = tags ?? string.Empty;
     string[] tagNames = tags.Split(new char[]{' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            foreach(string tagName in tagNames)
              {
                post.Tags.Add(GetTag(tagNames));
              } 
       }

private Tag GetTag(string tagName)
    {
    return _context.Tags.Where(x => x.Name == tagName).FirstOrDefault() ??
    new Tag() { Name = tagName };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than creating a new method on the controller, you could encapsulate all the behaviour for parsing and searching for tags in a class, maybe something like this:

```
public class Tags
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<Tag> contextTags;
    private readonly string rawTags;

    public Tags(string tags, IEnumerable<Tag> contextTags)
    {
        this.rawTags = tags ?? string.Empty;
        this.contextTags = contextTags;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Tag> ToList()
    {
        List<Tag> tags = new List<Tag>();

        string[] tagNames = this.rawTags.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        foreach (string tagName in tagNames)
        {
            tags.Add(this.GetTag(tagName));
        }

        return tags;
    }

    private Tag GetTag(string tagName)
    {
        return this.contextTags.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == tagName) ?? new Tag { Name = tagName };
    }
}
```

Then the Create method on the controller becomes:

```
public ActionResult Create(int? id, string title, string body, DateTime datetime, string tags)
{
    Post post = GetPost(id);
    post.Title = title;
    post.Body = body;
    post.Tags.Clear();

    Tags tagsList = new Tags(tags, this._context.Tags);

    post.Tags = tagsList.ToList();
}
```

Comment: That's absolutely beautiful. Thanks!